# How get all request mappings in Spring boot after they've all been created?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to have a component that keeps some metadata about all request mappings. So I want to do two things:

1. Be able to grab all request mappings that exist when its `@PostConstruct` is called
2. Have some callback/event-listener so it adds any mappings added/removed later on

I am able to get the request mappings, but only at the time I call that actual class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class TestComponent
{
    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct()
    {
        doSomethingWithMappings();
    }

    public void doSomethingWithMappings()
    {
        //...elided...
    }
}
```

But I cannot find where I can listen for request mapping changes to update this.

Comment: You may get all mappings with spring boot actuator endpoint mappings
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints.
Here what do you mean by listener for request mapping change ?  As request mapping are not supposed to change at runtime.

Comment: @abhi3232 I need it in the code, not from making an outside http call to an actuator endpoint. And by listener, I mean, if my component is loaded before all the request mappings are loaded, then I won't get them all in the PostConstruct.